# SQL Server: error 7303 (architecture mismatch)

Tags: sql-server, linked-server

I've searched a lot, but I still didn't find out a solution. I have to create a linked server to get the data from a mdb file (MS Access). I use the SQL Server 2012 Express x64 on the Windows 8.1 x64. I ran the odbcad x32 (the one that's inside the syswow64 folder), so I created the data source for this file:

[image]

But when I try to create the linked server I got the error:

[image]

Searching, I found out that the x64 SQL Server server can use any x32 driver. I can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: My experience has been that an x64 version of SQL Server is *not* able to use a 32-bit driver.  I would try downloading and installing the 64-bit version of the Access driver (on the SQL host, of course).

Comment: I see. I installed a new instance of the SQL Server 2012 Express x32 and now I can use the drivers. Thank you so much.